# Mail.app and fonts

Tags: apple-mail

Im a new mac user and whenever I send an email using Mail.app, the fonts are not the same when seen on Outlook 2010. And in both Gmail/Outlook the signature alone looks pretty different, while it looked identical on Mail.app when composing.

How to handle this

Answer (score 0):

Use fonts which are likely to be present on Windows machines as well as on Macs; when you compose the signature, you're given a choice of all the fonts your system has available, which likely doesn't match those available on the Windows machine where you're reading your mail in Outlook.

Or, as a preferable alternative, just don't try to be more specific than "proportional" or "fixed width" with the fonts in your signature, and avoid using a signature which relies on a specific font or fonts to be properly displayed. As with any HTML content intended to be read on various clients with various installed font sets, you're more or less guaranteed sooner or later to send mail to somebody who doesn't have whatever fonts you chose; if the appearance of your signature relies strongly on the properties of those specific fonts, then when that person reads your mail, the signature's not going to look right.